# insert into pipe pg_insert

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have a long generated print command written in bash with the output something like this :

```
insert into shema VALUES ('ALARM1cf',NULL, 0, 0,255,'ALARM CATEGORY:Command Failed ', ' 1147661553' ,'Ping command failed ', 171,2);
```

I'd like to pipe it to an pg_insert command which connect to an pgsql database. It does not work if I redirect the print command this way :

```
print " the generated commands " | /place/of/script/pg_insert &
```

I tried to do it manualy, and it works this way :

```
pg_insert " insert into shema ... values ('...','...' );"
```

What could be the difference between these methods? What else could I try?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious... in the first (not working) case you pass the command to pg_insert **standard input**, in the second case you pass the insert statement to pg_insert as **command line argument**. Maybe pg_insert reads INSERT commands from it's command line and not from its stdin.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help! Do you have an idea how to solve this problem? Maybe i should cat the commands in a file and execute from there?

Comment: I would just create a small program that reads from stdin and call pg_insert passing everything via command line... Something like... `while read cmd ; do pg_insert "$cmd" ; done` or so. You might want to avoid the while loop if you want to run just one cmd at a time....

Comment: It works, thanks once again!